# Excluding region prefix from domain in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to run a private server for an older game that's no longer supported by the developers. The main executable for that game sends requests to an old elastic beanstalk URL which hasn't been in use for some years now. I can get players to join by letting them change their DNS settings, but ideally I would love for the game to natively start working again.

The problem is that in 2016 Amazon made a change that includes the region prefix each time you create an environment.  More info here: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/01/aws-elastic-beanstalk-adds-support-for-amazon-route-53-aliasing/

The formatting looks like this:

- Old URL: oldgame.elasticbeanstalk.com
- New URL: oldgame.eu-north-1.elasticbeanstalk.com

My question(s) then are:

- Is it at all possible to get that old format to work in AWS somehow?
- If it is not possible, would it be likely at all for Amazon to help configuring it this way? I do not currently have a support plan where I can ask them a question like this. I would not mind paying, but perhaps this is not even worth the effort. Hoping to get some insight here.